# Why isn't my Minecraft detect command working when executed by a command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I now have this command:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:sandstone 0 effect @a[c=1] minecraft:slowness 2 1
```

When I run this from the chat it works fine, it gives me slowness when I stand on sandstone and no slowness when I don't. but when I run this from a command block, it says

```
Failed to execute 'detect' as [my name]
```

Why is this? Why won't my command work when executed by a command block?

Comment: Tip: Replace `@a[c=1]` with `@s` for more accuracy and less side-effects.

Comment: You get the same error message in chat when you don't stand on sandstone. What else would you expect?

Answer (score 1):

As Fabian commented, use @s [target selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_variables), instead of the @a[c=1].  This target selector selects the entity executing the command.  You are using the execute command so this would select the player that has sandstone beneath them.

---

This 'error' is indicating that the detect portion did not detect sandstone below the player.

It will say this every time it executes and it does not detect sandstone, I am standing on stone here:
[image: Error]

Exact same command while standing on sandstone, no error and I have slowness:
[image: Non Error]

Comment: I fixed it now (I don't know how but it works), but it also gave that message when I was standing on sandstone

Comment: If you had it in a Repeat Always Active command block, I have had them 'stick' after setting them once in a while.  I usually fix it by switching them to Needs Redstone clicking Done and then setting them back to Always Active.